# PHP Switch case problem, always returns an error

Tags: php, html, switch-statement, oracle-call-interface

I have a web page where in I input a string and via $POST it goes to the PHP script, performs a SQL select there and returns the data on the page. For one single select query is working fine. But I am trying to include other Selects statements as well for searching with other values as well.

So when I run my php,(which is from a web page) without switch, It always performs as I expect it to. Without errors.

```
 <html>
<!-- some style ... -->
<?php

$HOST="10.133.96.132";

// Database user
$DBUSER="tibco";

// Database password
$PASS="suyash123";

// Database name
$DB="VFD2TEST";

// Database Error - User Message
$DB_MSG_ERROR='Could not connect!<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.';


############## Make the mysql connection ###########

$conn = oci_connect ($DBUSER, $PASS, "//10.133.96.132:7041/VFD2TEST");

if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
$select123 = $_POST['value'];
$output123 = shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'");

switch ($output123) 
{
     case "QUERY1":
        $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE TUX_ADAPTERS='".$_POST['value']."'";
         $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
         oci_execute($result);
         break;
     case "QUERY2":
            $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE COMPONENT='".$_POST['value']."'";
            $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
            oci_execute($result);
         break;
     case "QUERY3":
        $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE TUX_SERVICES='".$_POST['value']."'";
            $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
            oci_execute($result);
         default:
         $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE STATION_NAME='".$_POST['value']."'";
         $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
         oci_execute($result);
         break;
 }

echo '<TABLE>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>ADAPTERS</th>
    <th>SERVICE</th>
        <th>CALLING_APP</th>
        <th>BP_NAME</th>
        <th>STATION_NAME</th>
         <th style="padding-right:20px;">COMPONENT</th>
        </tr>';
echo '</thead>';
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
{

  echo '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[5].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[6].'</td>

</tr>';

}


echo '</TABLE>';

oci_free_statement($result);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</html>
```

Output of the following is:

```
 $select123 = $_POST['value'];
    $output123 = shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'");
```

is QUERY1

so it should switch

=================================EDIT====================================

I just tried with the if else statement, the first queries don't fetch the data anyway, although the query listed in default is working just fine and its the same query.

=============================================================================

================================EDIT2=========================================

Now I have trimmed the variable so no issue of spaces or special characters

```
<html>
<!-- some style ... -->
<?php

$HOST="10.xxx.xxx.132";

// Database user
$DBUSER="tibco";

// Database password
$PASS="xxxxx";

// Database name
$DB="TEST";

// Database Error - User Message
$DB_MSG_ERROR='Could not connect!<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.';


############## Make the mysql connection ###########

$conn = oci_connect ($DBUSER, $PASS, "//10.xxxx.96.xx:xxx/xxxx");

if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
$select123 = $_POST['value'];
$output123 = shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'");
$output234 = trim($output123);
echo $output234;
if ($output234=="QUERY3")
{
$c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE COMPONENT='".$_POST['value']."'";  
}
else if ($output234=="QUERY1")
{

$c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE TUX_ADAPTERS='".$_POST['value']."'";
}   
$result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
oci_execute($result);

echo '<TABLE>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>ADAPTERS</th>
    <th>SERVICE</th>
        <th>CALLING_APP</th>
        <th>BP_NAME</th>
        <th>STATION_NAME</th>
         <th style="padding-right:20px;">COMPONENT</th>
        </tr>';
echo '</thead>';
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
{

  echo '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[5].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[6].'</td>

</tr>';

}


echo '</TABLE>';

oci_free_statement($result);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</html>
```

Now my out put is QUERY1 and QUERY3 respectively but the result is not there, earlier the query which looks for STATION_NAME was working now the one which looks for COMPONENT is working and not the station name one. Really strange.

Comment: In your code block `$select123 = $_POST;` is missing `['value']`

Comment: Is there also a space in the output? `case "QUERY1 "`

Comment: @Nick Hi Nick, I started with the $_POST['value'], didn't help

Comment: @Suyash well you can't use $_POST as that is an array, and you will get Array to String conversion errors.

Comment: @Nick I tried this

<?php


$select123 = "TUXXMK-R";

$output123=shell_exec("cat data.lst|grep $select123|awk -F: '{print $2}'");

$output=$output123;
echo $output123;
echo $output;

switch ($output123) {
     case "QUERY1 ":
echo $select123;
break;
     case "QUERY2 ":
    echo $output123;
break;
         default:
echo "error";
 }

?>

I got the output as 

QUERY1 QUERY1 error

Comment: So what is the value in `$output123` for that case? is it `"QUERY1"` or is it `"QUERY1 "`? If it's the former, it won't match the values in your switch statement.

Comment: @Nick  put already trimmed data in the file "data.lst" so it should not return a space, I did the same thing initially(cases without spaces) but it didn't work then I changed it to spaces because I could pick up the "QUERY1" paste in the search bar and there was one extra space in the end. But I have tried both ways doesn't work.

Comment: @Lewis Yes Lewis I tried that as well :(

Comment: `if ($output234="QUERY3")` should be `if ($output234==="QUERY3")` etc...

Comment: Looks like you are playing with fire. You are inserting unvalidated POST data into a shell_exec(). If somebody wants to do any harm, they can inject any command they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to run it with the Switch statement, but was able to do it with the help of if...else

here is the code

```
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
$select123 = $_POST['value'];
$output123 = shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'");
$output234 = trim($output123);
if ($output234=="QUERY3")
{
        $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE COMPONENT='".$_POST['value']."'";  
        $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
        oci_execute($result);
} 
//else if ($output234=="QUERY1")

    //{
        //$c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE TUX_ADAPTERS='".$_POST['value']."'"; 
        //$result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
        //oci_execute($result);

    //}

else if ($output234=="QUERY2")

    {
        $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE TUX_SERVICES='".$_POST['value']."'";   
        $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
        oci_execute($result);

    }

else

    {
        $c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE STATION_NAME='".$_POST['value']."'";   
        $result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
        oci_execute($result);

    }   

echo '<TABLE>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>ADAPTERS</th>
    <th>SERVICE</th>
        <th>CALLING_APP</th>
        <th>BP_NAME</th>
        <th>STATION_NAME</th>
         <th style="padding-right:20px;">COMPONENT</th>
        </tr>';
echo '</thead>';
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
{

  echo '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[5].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[6].'</td>

</tr>';

}


echo '</TABLE>';

oci_free_statement($result);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</html>
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss ['value'] in $select123 and the break in case "QUERY3 ".

Then you can simplify your code like this:

```
$conn = oci_connect ($DBUSER, $PASS, "//YY.XXX.ZZ.132:XXXX/TEST");

if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
$select123 = $_POST;
$output123 = shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'");
$c = "SELECT * FROM EAITUXSERVICES WHERE ";
switch ($output123) {
     case "QUERY1 ":
        $c .= "TUX_ADAPTER";
     break;
     case "QUERY2 ":
        $c .= "COMPONENT";
     break;
     case "QUERY3 ":
        $c .= "TUX_SERVICES";
     break;
     default:
         $c .= "STATION_NAME";
     break;
 }
$c .= "='".$_POST['value']."'";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $c);
oci_execute($result);

echo '<TABLE>';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>ADAPTERS</th>
    <th>SERVICE</th>
        <th>CALLING_APP</th>
        <th>BP_NAME</th>
        <th>STATION_NAME</th>
         <th style="padding-right:20px;">COMPONENT</th>
        </tr>';
echo '</thead>';
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
{

  echo '
  <tr>
    <td>'.$row[0].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[1].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[3].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[4].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[5].'</td>
    <td>'.$row[6].'</td>

</tr>';

}


echo '</TABLE>';

oci_free_statement($result);
oci_close($conn);

?>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried adding $_POST['value'], nothing happens. That's how Initially I was doing it.

Comment: At this point you should give us more information. Try to print $output123 before the switch.

Comment: I just tried this


<?php


$select123 = "TUXXMK-R";

$output123=shell_exec("cat data.lst|grep $select123|awk -F: '{print $2}'");

$output=$output123;
echo $output123;
echo $output;

switch ($output123) {
     case "QUERY1 ":
echo $select123;
break;
     case "QUERY2 ":
    echo $output123;
break;
         default:
echo "error";
 }

?>

output is QUERY1 QUERY1 error 

I copy pasted the output there

Comment: Are you sure your cases have a space? Try to trim that.

Comment: I put already trimmed data in the file "data.lst" so it should not return a space, I did the same thing initially(cases without spaces) but it didn't work then I changed it to spaces because I could pick up the "QUERY1" paste in the search bar and there was one extra space in the end.

Comment: I have a sql developer, so I executed the query its proper. In the switch cases I removed the post variable and used it, the query works fine. It could be a special character and not a space but I copied it and it should work but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Real answer I feel should look just `trim`:

```
$output123 = trim(shell_exec("cat data.lst |grep $select123| awk -F: '{print $2}'"));

switch ($output123) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: yep this is better than what I did. :)